# Why is the new constraint layout not using layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf and layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf as standard?

Tags: android, right-to-left

I have been using relative layouts and it is suggested to use endOf and startOf to make it easier to convert western left to right views to right to left. Was just wondering why isn't this cannon yet?

Comment: imho, because not every application need to support rtl.